# Custom column names for auto generated table from java map object using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have Entity that  contains map of two entities.
First one which is a question class is a key. Second entity which is an answer class is a value.

Here is entity code:

```
@Entity
public class SurveyForm {
    @OneToMany
    public Map<SurveyFormQuestion, SurveyFormAnswer> questionAndAnswer;
}
```

JPA/Hibernates generate two MySql table:

First:  **SurveyForm**, which is the fact an empty one.

Second: **SurveyForm_SurveyFormAnswer**, which goes as follow:

```
SurveyForm_id           bigint(20)          SurveyForm -> id         
questionAndAnswer_id    bigint(20)          SurveyFormAnswer -> id       
questionAndAnswer_KEY   bigint(20)          SurveyFormQuestion -> id
```

I would like to declare somehow names for table: **SurveyForm_SurveyFormAnswer**'s columns, and instead of

- `questionAndAnswer_id` I would like to have: `answer`
- `questionAndAnswer_KEY` I would like to have: `question`

My question is:

Is this even possible via `JPA/Hiberate` and if How to do it.

Please help

---

EDIT
Just for clarification, I post here working solution:

---

```
@Entity
public class SurveyForm {
    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    @JoinTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="answer_id"))
    public Map<SurveyFormQuestion, SurveyFormAnswer> questionAndAnswer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@MapKeyJoinColumn` and `@JoinColumn`:

```
@Entity
public class SurveyForm {
    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "question")
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="answer"))
    public Map<SurveyFormQuestion, SurveyFormAnswer> questionAndAnswer;
}
```

Comment: I've added those annotation, but now jpa doesn't create that table at all. Also I don't get any error.

Comment: Can you try it with `@JoinTable(joinColumns=JoinColumn(name="answer"))` instead of `@JoinColumn`?

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting an error: `name cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: You mean an compile error? I've missed an `@`: `@JoinTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="answer"))`

Comment: I've adjusted my answer - it seams that you always need to use `@JoinTable`, if there is an extra mapping table. A standalone `@JoinColumn` is only working for a column that is in the entity table.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a 100% on your code, but if you wish to name your custom tables using JPA, you can specify them with the `@Table` and `@Column` annotations, e.g.:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SurveyFormQuestion")
public class SurveyFormQuestion{

    @Column(name = "question")
    public String question;
}
```

I hope this helps and answers your question, try to play around with it a little.

Comment: I am aware of this annotation, but it work only for **hard coded** `Entities` and their `parameters`. In my case whole SQL Table is generated from one `Map`. I have no place to put this annotations.